# flashvars not working on Android Browser

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flex4, flashvars

I have a flex app that I need to pass FlashVars into.
It works great on desktop browsers(chrome, firefox, ie) but for some reason the flashvar is always undefined when i load it on my Android browser(webkit on a droid incredible).

Has anyone successfully passed flashvars into a swf on an Android Device?

Comment: IS there any flash plugin installed ?

Comment: Could you pass on the link of your application? Or at least the code where you embed your Flash in HTML?

Comment: try passing data get variables

Comment: sorry i didnt get any notifications that my post had replies.

Comment: sorry i didnt get any notifications that my post had replies. here is the code.... 
the code is at git://gist.github.com/851662.git   flash is installed on the device.

Comment: Could you post some of your code !? Perhaps it could help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a querystring instead - they're passed in identically to FlashVars (loaderInfo.parameters)

your-app.swf?var1=bob&var2=true

Comment: THanks for the response. I actually tried this as well and couldn't get it to work on this application. I have passed in vars using both methods countless times with no problems. At this point I have abandoned this little project :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="name=a"
```

Seems your missing /> in your code on the git. I am not sure if this was the only issue or not but it could be.